# Modeling Item Size in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design, model, data-modeling

I have an Item model, that can be clothing, shoes, or bags (category).
I also have the Size model, that represents the Size of the Item.

The issue is:
For clothing, size can be: XS, S, M, L, XL
For shoes, size can be: 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5

Also, the shoe size depends if it is UK or US or European, so a UK 6 is a US 7 and European 40.

How should I model this?
Everything as a single Size model?
Should I have child models?
Or should I have many different models (ShoeSize, ClothingSize)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If any of the answers has helped then please vote up. If an answer was able to solve your problem then you should mark it as accepted. If the answers didn't work please comment on what went wrong. If you've solved the problem another way then please write that solution in your own answer (you can answer your own questions)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you require an 'Item' catch-all model?

The two ways I might do this are:

1) I would either have separate models for clothes, shoes and bags. Each model would have it's own individual size attribute.

I would also do their size attributes as a collection with "US 6" etc as separate options.

or

2) If you want to keep them all under one 'Item' model . Make their type (i.e. shoes, clothes, bags) an enumeration (Example included below). Then I would make a different column in my table for each type of size for example: Item would have an attribute that is `:clothes_size` that is a collection with your S,M,L,XL and then a `:shoes_size` with it's own selection etc.Then you can just display the field that is necessary for that item.

Enumerations look like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
enum type: [:shoes, :clothing, :bags] 
end
```

What the enumeration will do is make it so you have an attribute to put them into categories; mapping each one to an integer in the db. (0=shoes, 1=clothing, 2=bags)

Then you will need to run a migration. 
`rails g migration AddTypeToItem type:integer`

It will also auto generate a bunch of super cool built in methods for you to sort and find your objects by type, such as

`@item.shoes?` etc. Read more about them [in the Rails API.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Comment: Hey Chris thanks a lot for your answer. I was thinking about polymorphic associations too, do you think that it could work too?

Comment: They definitely could. With a lot of these types of situations it's really dependent on what the scope of what you are trying to do. What are you thinking with Polymorphic associations?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the item category as an enumeration as @ChiefRockaChris suggested, then I would do this:

make the size attribute an integer and map these integers to a different set of strings according to item category. I would come up with a standard measurement unit for shoe size (like mm) then have another function that maps that measurement to UK, US or European.

This code would go in your Item class

```
def self.sizes
  {
    clothing: {1: 'XS', 2: 'S', 3: 'M', 4: 'L', 5: 'XL'},
    shoe: {1: '35mm', 2: '40mm', 3: '45mm'}
  }
end

def self.shoes_size_type
  {
    UK: {'35mm' => '6', '40mm' => '7', '45mm' => '8'},
    US: {'35mm' => '7', '40mm' => '8', '45mm' => '9'},
    Europe: {'35mm' => '35', '40mm' => '40', '45mm' => '45'}
  }
end

def self.size_parsed
   sizes[category][size]
end

def self.shoe_size(country)
  shoe_size_type[country][size_parsed] or size_parsed
end
```